# JIRA API to Google Sheets -- DNS error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, jira-rest-api

I would love some insight or pointers into what might be causing this DNS error that I'm encountering. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- I would like to pull data from JIRA using their API and have the data placed into a precreated Google Sheet
- I can currently connect to our JIRA environment using a curl command and base 64 encoding via the Mac Terminal

`curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=” -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://jira.ourworkdomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/XXX-1000”`

I've tried recreating something very similar in a Google Sheet script. It looks like the following:

```
function connectToJira() {

  var encCred = "dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=";
  var url = "https://jira.ourworkdomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/XXX-1000";
  var options = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "headers": {"Authorization": "Basic "+encCred}, 
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Browser.msgBox(response.getContentText());
}
```

When I run the script in debug mode it highlights...

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

... and gives me the following error:

> DNS error: https://jira.ourworkdomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/XXX-1000
>   (line 12, file "Code") Dismiss

When I expand all the variables I can see that "response" comes back as undefined.

Any ideas or leads on how I can overcome this issue? There may be a simple step I'm missing some place that I just don't know about it or just a lack of understanding on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is https://jira.ourworkdomain.com accessible publicly on the Internet?

If not, this will not work. The URL Fetch service makes requests from Google public IP addresses to the public Internet.

From the [URLFetchApp class documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

> This service allows scripts to communicate with other applications or
> access other resources on the web by fetching URLs.
>
> ...
>
> Requests made
> using this service originate from a set pool of IP ranges. You can
> [look up the full list of IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) if you need to whitelist or
> approve these requests.

Comment: That must be it. I don't believe it's publicly accessible.With that being said, is there another way to work around this or another function I could use that accomplishes the same thing? Thanks for pointing this out chuckx.

Comment: Apps Script isn't well suited to the task, due to internal resources being involved. An alternative approach is creating a script that runs on your workstation (or a server in your environment) that starts off by getting data from Jira then uses the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) to populate your spreadsheet. There are language specific quickstart guides, so you can use whatever's most familiar (i.e. use the [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) if you want to stick to JavaScript).